# npm package.json multiple registries

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

We have internal nexus npm repository in which i have published my first component. `my-component@1.0.0` we also have npm proxy which goes and out in the world and gets global npm dependencies.

in my .npmrc i have defined registry as

```
registry=http://my.interal.proxy:8081/repository/npmjs-proxy
strict-ssl=false
```

my internal npm repo which has `my-component@1.0.0` is

```
http://my.interal.repo:8081/repository/npm
```

is there a way i can tell package.json to download `my-component@1.0.0` from my internal repo and rest of them from proxy.

in other post i read about create a group of npm and proxy registries like `npm-all` and use that one. but rite now i am looking for client side solution.